# Playwright waitForFunction for mouse?

Tags: storybook, playwright

I would like to make a screenshot of a hovered button in storybook. My code not working with headless browsers and I probably need to wait some more but can't seem to figure it out. I'm very grateful for any tips.

```
test('example test', async ({ url }) => {
  const browser = firefox.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 300 });
  const page = await (await browser).newPage();
  await page.goto(
    'url'
  );

  await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' });
  await page.waitForSelector('#storybook-preview-iframe');

  const elementHandle = await page.$('#storybook-preview-iframe');
  const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
  await frame.waitForSelector('button[id=btn]');
  const el = await frame.$('button[id=btn]');

  const box = await el.boundingBox();

  // const watchDog = page.waitForFunction(
  //   page => {
  //     page.mouse;   ??????????????? I know that there is no mouse.getCurrentPosition method
  //   },
  //   {},
  //   page
  // );
  await page.mouse.move(box.x + box.width / 2, box.y + box.height / 2);

  //await watchDog;

  expect(await page.screenshot()).toMatchSnapshot('screenshot.png');
});
```

Comment: Maybe resolve it using the mouse over event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.hover()` as this method will scroll view into the selected element then move the cursor over the element.

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.5.1&show=api-pagehoverselector

```
test('example test', async ({ url }) => {
  const browser = firefox.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 300 });
  const page = await (await browser).newPage();
  await page.goto(
    'url'
  );

  await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' });
  await page.waitForSelector('#storybook-preview-iframe');

  const elementHandle = await page.$('#storybook-preview-iframe');
  const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
  await frame.waitForSelector('button[id=btn]');

  await frame.hover('button[id=btn]')

  expect(await page.screenshot()).toMatchSnapshot('screenshot.png');
});
```

That's it. Hope this will work.